# persistent error when using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

i want to use simple_html_dom on url

i used this :

```
include_once('/simple_html_dom.php');
```

but returns this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in test.php on line 9
```

I CHMOD directory and the file to 777 , but no change.

I used this method :

```
$file = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."../simple_html_dom.php");
include_once($file);
```

but returns an error : filename cannot be empty.

SAFE_MODE is ON and i'm not the server admin.

any ideas ?

Comment: The error refers to a function find() in test.php Please post the code of that function

Comment: @Pankrates the file test.php has no functions. I thought this function is in simple_html_dom .

Comment: So which error are you receiving right now? The 'Fatal error'? Please post (copy-paste) the exact error message

Comment: I receive this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/zizoforu/public_html/lab/test.php on line 9`

Comment: Well error indicates exactly where the problem is, in the file test.php. If you are absolutely sure that it does not exist than I can not help any further